# Select2 adds an empty span that I can't remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a multiple select defined in this way:

```
<select class="form-control" name="citiesNotValid">
```

If I initialize it as select2 it duplicates the select elements, one working and filled with my preselected option, and the other empty and not working.
This is the inizialization of the select2:

```
    $(s).select2({
    language: "it",
    placeholder: {
        id: '-1', // the value of the option
        text: 'All'
    },
    width: '100%',
    //multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        delay: 500,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: o,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: 1,
        data: function (params) {
            var query = JSON.stringify({
                country_code: country,
                search: params.term
            })

            return query;
        },
        processResults: function (t) {
            return {
                results: $.map(JSON.parse(t.d), function (obj) {
                    if (obj.city_name == "-") {
                        return { id: "-1", text: "Tutte" };
                    }
                    return { id: obj.city_name, text: obj.city_name };

                })
            };
        },
        error: function (t, o, i) {
            var n = "Si è verificato un errore. Controlla di aver passato correttamente tutti i parametri.";
            //if (t.statusText != null && t.statusText != "")
            // n = t.statusText;
            "toastr" == a && toastr ? toastr.error(n) : "notific8" == a && $.notific8 ? ($.notific8("zindex", 11500), $.notific8(n, {
                theme: "ruby",
                life: 3e3
            })) : console.log(n)
        }
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
});
```

}

When I run the code in this way, it  creates a second `<span>` element, I can see it in my Chrome console, but if I try to delete it in my jQuery code I can't find it, like it doesn't exist.
[image]
[image]

Another thing that I noted is that if I add to my select the `select2` class, it creates only one select, but Ajax isn't triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an empty `option` as first element of you html select? If so, try removing it.

Comment: No, I haven't an empty option as first

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you are not linking the select2 style sheet to you page.